# Help with UV mapping

Tags: materials

I am new to this website, I need some help with UV mapping. I have created a material with 4 image texture nodes with one of them being a normal map texture node. But the normal map has a different texture in it and I am trying to edit the UV mapping of the normal map texture without editing the UV mapping of the other textures in the same material. How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't edit UV mapping for one texture while not editing it for the other; you have 2 options generally. Either create another UV map for another texture and make edits there,or make all textures use the same UV map and adjust textures accordingly (place A on the texture-1 corresponds to the place A on the texture-B). The first method has downside that mesh can have no more than 8 UV maps.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do. Have you tried using a mapping node to alter the ccordinatas and/or scale of the texture?